# Android : Listview stuff

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter

I have a listview displaying list of items and a button at the bottom. On click of button, i'am displaying one alert dailog box to take input from user and adding that input to the listview. 
 1. How can i make sure the new input/entry should add always at top of listview? (Right now it is adding at bottom always)
2. Is it possible to position the list view at the new entry? (i.e if the new entry is added at top, the list should be positioned at the top)
Please guide me.

Inside onCreate()...

```
    list  = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.planetList); 
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyListViewActivity.this, 
R.layout.my_list_row, R.id.planetNameTextView); 

        for (int i = 0; i < planetNamesArray.length; i++) { 
        adapter.add(planetNamesArray[i]); 
        } 
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

After taking input from user ....

```
    adapter.add(newPlanetNameEnteredByUser);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **listview.setStackFromBottom(false)** to fill your listview from top.

this link may help you.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setStackFromBottom%28boolean%29

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that, have two List.

```
List<String> old = new ArrayList<String>();  // contains your list content
List<String> new = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now, when you want to add new content to ListView then add it first to the new ArrayList,

```
new.add("new content");
new.addAll(old); // add all the old contents
new.setSelection(position_you_want);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the object in array list

```
ArrayList<String> List= new ArrayList<String>();
ListView ListName= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.playerdata);
```

with

```
 List.add(index, "value");

public void add (int index, E object)
```

**Since: API Level 1 
Inserts the specified object into this ArrayList at the specified location. The object is inserted before any previous element at the specified location. If the location is equal to the size of this ArrayList, the object is added at the end.
Parameters
index  the index at which to insert the object. 
object  the object to add.**

Throws

```
IndexOutOfBoundsException  when location < 0 || > size()
```

and set list adapter

```
ListName.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
        (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , List));
```